# The type name ____ does not exist in the type ____

Tags: c#, .net, class

I know the question is already out there. But i cant solve my problem with the other solutions. I want to create a List out of Lists.

My Code:

```
class SomeClassName
{
   static List<char> saveFields = new List<char>();

        public static List<char> SaveFields
        {
            get { return saveFields; }
            set { saveFields = value; }
        }
}

public void someMethod
{
   List<SomeClassName.SaveFields> someListName = new List<SomeClassName.SaveFields>();
}
```

My Namespace is TicTacToe so there is no name issue.
How can i solve this error?

I get the error for "SaveFields"

Comment: So namespace is same on both?  is the "someMethod" in the same class as saveFields?

Comment: Yes namespace is same on both. Yes the someMethod is in the same class. But however i tried it already in another class.

Comment: Doesn't work with fields, it will work if you do `List<SomeClassName>`

Comment: @12seconds but then you need to remove the `static` - which probably should be done anyway

Answer (score 6):

`SomeClassName.SaveFields` isn't a type, it is a property. The type of that property is `List<char>`. If you want to create a variable with the same type, you have to use `List<char>`.

You can assign that value to the variable though:

```
public void someMethod()
{
   List<char> someListName = SomeClassName.SaveFields;
}
```

Comment: Tank you. But i would like to have like a 2 dimensional list. So i would like to create a list of lists.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using generics?

```
class SomeClassName
{
   static List<T> saveFields = new List<T>();

        public static List<T> SaveFields
        {
            get { return saveFields; }
            set { saveFields = value; }
        }
}
```

It is insanely good, useful but machine resource hunger, use carefully

Comment: "useful but machine resource hunger", say what? From where did you get that idea?

Comment: It is compiled into the assembly, so it is no worse than non-generic code.

Comment: Reflection uses a lot of CPU cycles and memory in the worst case scenario, off course, it depends on who you use it. but the best option is always set the variable type on compiling time instead of execution time. There is no free lunch.

Comment: Generics have nothing to do with reflection. And as said, it is all done on compile time, generics don't have any execution time implications.